# Cannot find any sampes for Caliburn Micro with Prism

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, prism, caliburn.micro

I cannot find any samples that show Caliburn Micro combined with Prism. Prism is more of a modularity framework and Caliburn is more of a MVVM framework, I know both have overlapping features, but it would be great to take best features from two frameworks when they are combined. Does anyone have any samples? For example, bootstrappers are different, how would you get it working with both framework?

Comment: The HelloScreens sample that comes with CM is a good example of doing modules with CM so is http://mediaowl.codeplex.com/.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason why you can't find anything is because CM is enough. You don't need Prism when you're using CM. But you can look [here](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/225686) It's really old thread but still. There is probably nobody who would recommend integrating CM with Prism. There is simply no reason to do it.

Comment: How about Prism's modularity which CM doesn't have. I know I could use MEF, but I prefer Prism though.

Comment: @fenix2222 As you said... Prism is more "Composite applications framework" and CM is MVVM Framework, so in Prism it should be easier, but on the other hand there are ways to do that with CM and people have done it before. Look [here](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/254102) and maybe [here](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/240677). Please read it. It's long time since you posted this question so you are probably no more concerned by this, but if you are I would probably listen to what Rob Eisenberg said. Prism is covered by CM. But of course you can also choose Prism

Comment: @fenix2222 And also I have read that [MVVMlight](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/documentation) as a MVVM framework is pretty suitable for Prism applications. But it's your decision to make.